# How to populate after an aggregate in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, mongoose-populate

I have the following object and I need to populate the employeeId with name, employeeCode, department and fulltime.

The populate was working whe I was using myCollection.find(), but I have to use myCollection.aggregate instead, and it is not possible to use populate.

Below you can see my get I had so far. How to populate the employeeId (with name, employeeCode, department and fulltime)?

**OBJECT**

```
`
_id: ObjectId('64036f7ac0829fe25c6ef435')
clockIn: 2023-03-04T06:28:06.433+00:00
clockOut: 2023-03-04T10:30:08.601+00:00
employeeId: ObjectId('63feed3c60a04fbc61c52f91')
createdAt: 2023-03-04T16:19:06.436+00:00
updatedAt: 2023-03-04T16:19:08.601+00:00
__v: 0
`
```

**GET**

```
timesheetRouter.get('/timesheet', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const clockInOutTimesheet = await Timesheet.aggregate([
      { $group: {_id: '$employeeId', totalHours: { $sum: { $subtract: ['$clockOut', '$clockIn'] } },    
     }, 
    },
  ])

  console.log("GET ==> ",clockInOutTimesheet)

  res.json(clockInOutTimesheet);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
}
});
```

Comment: I think you need a lookup but can you confirm what’s your expected output is?

Comment: Hello, I tried to use lookup but did not work as well. What I need is to populate the employeeId. EmployeeId brings name, department, employeeCode and fulltime. EmployeeId belongs to another model (or collection) and I do not know how to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [`$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)stage

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$employeeId",
      totalHours: {
        $sum: {
          $subtract: [
            "$clockOut",
            "$clockIn"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "employees",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "employee"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            $first: "$employee"
          },
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "employee"
  }
```

Note the `$replaceRoot` and `$unset` stages to lift the lookup result to root level

[Working demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3FnJ515AfI6)